# C# Parse XML file into object from given tag

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I have an xml file and the dataset that I want to make into an object is encapsulated by another tag, so when I try and parse it, of course it throws an InvalidOperationException, due to the unexpected member.

I've tried reading various MS Docs about xml, as well as googling my problem, but I couldn't find how could I solve it without too much hussle.

My code:

```
public static ClassToDeserialize GetObjectFromXml (string path)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ClassToDeserialize));
        System.IO.FileStream file = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path);
        ClassToDeserialize loadedObjectXml = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(file) as ClassToDeserialize;
        return loadedLicenseXml;
    }
```

So how could I tell this program to start deserializing only from a specific tag, as that contains the object's related xml data?

Comment: IMHO you should use `XmlReader` to open up your XML file and then go through all the tags untill you find the one you want. Then you can use the same `XmlReader` to deserialize data you want or just get the `OuterXml` from that node and deserialize it using `XmlSerializer`

Comment: Use XML Reader and then you can readto method to get the tag you need : System.Xml.XmlReader reader = System.Xml.Create(file); reader.ReadToFollowing(tag);xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try read Xml up the point you find your node and then retrieve it's outer xml and put that into `XmlSerializer`. Let's say you have a simple XML file like this one:

```
<rootnode>
  <!-- some nodes inside -->
  <uselessNode>
    <thatsWhatIWant>
      <!-- some fields inside -->
      <uselessNodeInside/>
      <usefullNodeInside/>
    </thatsWhatIWant>
  </uselessNode>
</rootnode>
```

What you could do is open up `XmlReader`:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("path/to/myfile.xml");
```

Then read contents up to your POI and store that in some variable:

```
string wantedNodeContents = string.Empty;
while (reader.Read())
{
    if(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "thatsWhatIWant")
    {
        wantedNodeContents = reader.ReadOuterXml();
        break;
    }
}
```

Having this you should be able to use `XmlSerializer` like so:

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ClassToDeserialize));
System.IO.TextReader textReader = System.IO.StringReader(wantedNodeContents);
ClassToDeserialize loadedObjectXml = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(textReader) as ClassToDeserialize;
```

You can alternatively (or in addition to that) try to add some handlers for `UnknownNode` and `UnknownAttribute`:

```
xmlSerializer.UnknownNode+= new XmlNodeEventHandler(UnknownNode);
xmlSerializer.UnknownAttribute+= new XmlAttributeEventHandler(UnknownAttribute);

void UnknownNode(object sender, XmlNodeEventArgs e) { }
void UnknownAttribute(object sender, XmlAttributeEventArgs e) { }
```